# Connecting to kubernetes pod from java application

Tags: java, kubernetes

I have a pod at kubernetes cluster. I also have a service with a nodePort type for an external IP. Is there any way I can connect to my pod through external IP from java application?

Comment: Are you looking for any [kubernetes-client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java)? ee.g. [pod related api](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/wiki/3.-Code-Examples) or [port forwarding](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/examples/examples-release-12/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/examples/PortForwardExample.java) or [exec](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/examples/examples-release-12/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/examples/ExecExample.java)

Comment: @amitd I need to download some file from my pod after connection, will that help?

Comment: If you have any file transfer service [such as ftp/sfpt or other] running within the pod, then you can use sftp/ftp java client to copy that file from pod. If you do not have such a file transfer service running on pod, then you can attach/use any external storage to put these files on and then pull files from that storage. Else, refer [this](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/examples/examples-release-12/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/examples/CopyExample.java) example

Comment: @amitd I have samba server there. I think it use ftp. Is it?